# Strange Cursor behaviour

Tags: android, sqlite

Im using a listView to show a DataBase data (3 fields but just shows the name) and when I click 1 item, an AlertDialog shows up and I can see the other fields of that row, Im using a cursor to select the data and then just pass the strings that I want, but every time I press one I get a different element that expected, I know I could just make a query of the row I want to get, but Im so bad at SQLite so I rather doing it this way, here is the code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                Cursor crs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Usuarios", null);

                crs.moveToPosition(position);

                // get prompts.xml view
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                View promptsView1 = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog1, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView1);

                final TextView nam = (TextView) promptsView1
                        .findViewById(R.id.name1);
                nam.setText(crs.getString(0));

                final TextView ape = (TextView) promptsView1
                        .findViewById(R.id.apellido2);
                ape.setText(crs.getString(1));

                final TextView loc = (TextView) promptsView1
                        .findViewById(R.id.loc1);
                loc.setText(crs.getString(2));

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(true);

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
                //cursor = null;

            }
        });
```

Any help using this method or the one (Query sentence) would be appreciated

Comment: Don't use `rawQuery` and don't use `position` but use `id`. This is bound to break

Comment: What should I use instead of rawQuery? I have already tried using id, its long type though and anyways what is the point? In debugger Im getting same value for id and position

Comment: The position of an item can change between query1 and query2, its `id` will not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do. But I hope I could help.

First of all don't use `select *` when you just need one row, use a key column like ID.

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + TABLE + " where " + where, null);
```

Then if query returns a row, move cursor to first position and read the data

```
if (cursor != null)
   if (cursor.getCount() != 0)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        item.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ClassesConst.COLUMN_TEXT)));
```